# Loss of shinobi abilities after overusage of Mangekyou Sharingan

Tags: naruto

When a shinobi overuses the mangekyou sharingan, other than the vision (blindness), does he lose any other abilities as well? If so, what are they?

Comment: I have no clue why this has been down-voted.

Comment: I strongly disagree that my edit changed the meaning of the question. All I did was restate the question and provide information that might lead to an answer. The question body is for asking your question in a more detailed manner. As it is, this is not a question at all.

Comment: @ShayminGratitude It didn't change the meaning per say, but it was way to much of a change. Edits (if you are not the OP) are for fixing mistakes in things like grammar, spelling, or broken links and other similar things. Adding details is not one of those things, and you can only get away with it if the Op asked for it, which they did not in this case.

Comment: @SahanDeSilva Most likely its related to the 3 close votes I see for "unclear what you are asking". That is strange since it is clear what is being asked, crystal clear. I cant imagine how it could be interpreted in any way except as intended, unless you know nothing of Naruto. Its not a particularly great question, IMO not worth upvotes, But I do agree its not worth downvotes either, nor is that close reason actually a good reason to close the question. A proper grammar edit is in order though.

Comment: @Ryan That isn't quite right. Edits can be made for these reasons: To fix grammar and spelling mistakes, To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning),  To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place, To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages, To add related resources or hyperlinks. See https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/editing

Comment: This question needs a question body or it needs to be closed as unclear.

Comment: @ShayminGratitude That is only true for the OP, As I had said. If you are not the OP, adding details is a risk unless you have absolute proof they belong there. People who moderate these things are not necessarily experts on every anime. Sure, I who know Naruto know your edit was accurate, but if I didn't know about Naruto, I would have no idea where your edit came from. If you are OP, unless the edit is malicious, its left alone and the question is judged. If you are not OP, the edit is judged alone, and you changed the content without any backing from OP.

Comment: @ShayminGratitude FWIW, I decided to rollback your edit because SE discourages [spoonfeeding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183845/241919). You added more than 90% of the content, including Itachi's losing eyes which was not mentioned by the OP. The more proper way is to provide feedback to the OP how to improve it, e.g. by commenting.

Comment: It may be helpful to clarify in the question if/that they mean they go blind BECAUSE of the Mangekyo Sharingan. It is ambiguous in the question whether it is only referring to the blindness due to the Mangekyo Sharingan or to any blindness that might occur while having it (eg unrelated damage to the eye). Because I misunderstood at first.

Comment: I re-edited the question. Hope it's clear now

Answer (score 2):

I was also wondering for a bit as well as I do know that it eventually makes the user blind which leads them to snatching the eyes from a blood relative Sharingan user. Whether that impacts their abilities is something I wasn't sure of.

But, fret not, now I am!

Once Mangekyou Sharingan has been awakened, it grants them a lot nice extra's, but also the negative effect of turning blind over time. As far as I could find, the only negative effect is blindness, meaning that they retain their abilities from their eyes. Of course, it might be a bit difficult to cast Amaterasu accurately based on the sound of footsteps when you're blind, but that is essentially what is possible.

When they awaken the eternal variant, they can unlock eventually what they had with their original eyes. Meaning that in the end, they gain a lot more.

So in short to answer your question, no, you don't. You only lose your sight unless you have the eternal variant.

Source: [Naruto Wikia - Mangekyō Sharingan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan)

Comment: you could expand on this answer a bit by talking about Kakashi and his near blindness when he was helping Guy against Madara

Answer (score 0):

They do not lose fire-weilding and other genjustu learned however when they lose their sight they do lose the Sharingan abilities. What happens is their eyes lose light and in essence, die.  If they retained the eyes abilities, Madara would have had no need to steal as many eyes as he had, for his other senses would have filled in and in essence made the Sharingan stronger with practice without actual sight (much like Daredevil). Loss of sight= loss of Sharingan. That creates hatred among the clan though because when an Uchiha outuses his abilities, he steals them from another clan member.